# Different behavior in go1.5beta2 on MacOS and Linux

Tags: linux, macos, go

The example is taken from the "A Tour of Go": https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/1

Obviously, program output should have 10 rows: 5 for "hello" and 5 for "world".

But we have on:

- Linux - 9 rows
- MacOS - 10 rows

Linux output (9 rows):

```
$ go run 1.go 
hello
world
hello
world
hello
world
world
hello
hello
```

MacOS X output (10 rows):

```
$ go run 1.go 
hello
world
world
hello
hello
world
hello
world
hello
world
```

Can anyone explain - **why**?

Linux `uname -a`:

```
Linux desktop 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt11-1 (2015-05-24) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

MacOS X `uname -a`:

```
Darwin 14.5.0 Darwin Kernel Version 14.5.0: Thu Jul  9 22:56:16 PDT 2015; root:xnu-2782.40.6~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

Source code from tour:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func say(s string) {
    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
        time.Sleep(1000 * time.Millisecond)
        fmt.Println(s)
    }
}

func main() {
    go say("world")
    say("hello")
}
```

Comment: The main function finishes before the "world" goroutine can print for the fifth time. This is a race condition.

Comment: @inf, yep, also i got good answer from one of go collaborators https://github.com/golang/go/issues/11848#issuecomment-124226261

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the specification](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Program_execution):

> Program execution begins by initializing the main package and then invoking the function `main`. When that function invocation returns, the program exits. It does not wait for other (non-`main`) goroutines to complete.

So there is no guarantee that the goroutine printing `"world"` will have time to complete before the program exits.

I suspect that if you run the program enough times, you will see both the 9-line and 10-line outputs on both platforms.  Setting the `GOMAXPROCS` environment variable to 2 might also help in triggering the problem.

You can fix it by making the main goroutine explicitly wait for completion of the other goroutine.  For instance, using a channel:

```
func say(s string, done chan<- bool) {
    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
        time.Sleep(1000 * time.Millisecond)
        fmt.Println(s)
    }
    done <- true
}

func main() {
    c := make(chan bool, 2)
    go say("world", c)
    say("hello", c)
    <-c
    <-c
}
```

I've added a buffer to the channel so that the `say` function can send a value without blocking (primarily so the `"hello"` invocation actually returns).  I then wait receive two values from the channel to make sure both invocations have completed.

For more complex programs, the [`sync.WaitGroup`](http://golang.org/pkg/sync/#WaitGroup) type can provide a more convenient way to wait on multiple goroutines.